# Ionic 4 PWA - Can app be updated without deployment

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic4, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

Is it possible to update Ionic 4 progressive web app without deployment? For example, I wanted to just update a label change and I do not want to do a deployment so that customer does not have to reinstall the app.

I am at the moment using Cordova for build and firebase for notification. I am open to changing Cordova if required. Please suggest me the possibilities.

Comment: I think it is possible using app flow for ionic..

Comment: Ok. I will check it in detail. Initial impression is that it's a CI and CD tool. So not sure if we can do it. But I will check it anyways.